# Proving an integral is uniformly continuous: $f(x)=\int_{-\infty}^{x} e^{\frac{-t^2}{2}} dt$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, analysis, definite-integrals, uniform-continuity

> Prove that $f(x)=\int_{-\infty}^{x} e^{\frac{-t^2}{2}} dt$ for $x\in\mathbb{R}$ is uniformly continuous

Okay so I am unsure how to start this! I can prove a function is uniformly continuous but I'm not sure how to adapt that to an integral?

Comment: $|f(x)-f(y)|\le\int_x^y | e^{-t^2/2} |\,dt\le \int_x^y 1\,dt$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have
$$
f'(x)= e^{\frac{-x^2}{2}},\quad\forall x\in\mathbb{R},
$$ and
$$
\left|f'(x)\right|=\left| e^{\frac{-x^2}{2}}\right|\leq1,\quad\forall x\in\mathbb{R},
$$
hence by the [mean value theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem) we get
$$|f(x)-f(y)|\leq |x-y|\quad \forall x,y\in\mathbb{R}$$
so $f$ is a [lipschitzian function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lipschitz_continuity) on $\mathbb{R}$ and therefore it is uniformly continuous on $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: very nice.........+1@Olivier Oloa